# Angular ReactiveForms with custom object

Tags: angular

I have a question for understanding:

I have a custom object like this:

```
{
 name: 'foo',
 age: 12,
 city: 'LA'
}
```

I want to have a reactive Form with an input element. So I create a `FormControl` like this

```
fc: FormControl = new FormControl('');
```

I want to set the object as value:

```
this.fc.setValue(myCustomObjectFromAbove)
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="fc" ... />
```

However the input type="text" should just show the `name`. Do I need an `ControlValueAccessor` for this or can it be achieved easier?

Comment: Can't you create a form via formBuilder and set the value inside the formBuilder? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Set the name as value to the formControl

```
this.fc.setValue(myCustomObjectFromAbove.name);
```